# Dataset: sort rows in descending order of first column

Tags: dataset, row

I am new in the *Mathematica* community and I have a probably easy question for you regarding how to sort a dataset as the following so that I have sorted the values in the fist row descending from 44 in the first line down to 3 in the last line.

```
dataset = Dataset[{
  <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>, 
  <|"a" -> 8, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>, 
  <|"a" -> 44, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>, 
  <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>, 
  <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>, 
  <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

Comment: `dataset[SortBy[-#a &]]`.

Comment: ..... or `dataset[SortBy[a]][Reverse]`  ;-)

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much for the quick response!!

Comment: `dataset[SortBy[a] /* Reverse]`

Comment: `Reverse @ Sort@ ds`

Answer (score 6):

Let's gather all the answers in the comments here.

```
dataset[SortBy[-#a &]]
dataset[SortBy["a"]][Reverse]
dataset[SortBy["a"] /* Reverse]
Reverse @ Sort @ dataset
```

Comment: I corrected `SortBy[a]` to `SortBy["a"]`.  The former does produce the correct result, but that's just a coincidence.   It's in fact equivalent to a simple `Sort` and the symbol `a` makes no difference, one could write `b` or `c` and it wouldn't change the result.